# Python: OverflowError long int too large to convert to int

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, raspbian-stretch

After many years finding answers here, it's finally my time to ask my first question ever.

---

Running a RPI3B+ like a mini-server at home, I want to ba able to send large files to friends and family over internet, via CLI.
To do this, I am using this :
https://github.com/justbeamit/beam/blob/master/beam

But, when I want to upload a file larger than ~1.5Gb (*by my estimate*), I get an error saying :

```
OverflowError
long int too large to convert to int
```

After a short investigation, I can see that it comes from the line 288 where the max value of the progress bar is set, in this method :

```
def transfer(token, filePaths):

  print("recipient has connected! starting transfer...")

  uploadUrl = ACTIVE_BACKEND + "/upload"

  try:

    index = 0
    ProgressBar.totalNumberOfFiles = len(filePaths)

    for filePath in filePaths:

      # make the console look pretty
      sys.stdout.write("\n")
      print("  " + filePath)

      # the callback function invoked by the monitor
      def updateProgress(monitor):
        theProgressBar.update(monitor.bytes_read)


      # setup the multi-part encoder & its monitor
      fileMPE = getMultipartEncoder(filePath)
      monitor = MultipartEncoderMonitor(fileMPE, updateProgress)

      # setup the progress bar
      ProgressBar.fileNumber = index + 1 # to avoid showing (0 of 3)

      # since the progress bar will be updated by the multi-part encoder, we can't set 'maxval'
      # to be the file's size since the encoder adds extra bytes to account for the header
      theProgressBar = ProgressBar(
        maxval = len(fileMPE), 
        widgets = WIDGETS,
      )

      theProgressBar.start()

      urlParams = {
        "type": "CLI",
        "token": token,
        "index": index
      }

      requests.post(
        uploadUrl,
        data=monitor,
        params=urlParams,
        headers={'Content-Type': monitor.content_type}
      )

      theProgressBar.finish()
      index += 1
    # end for loop

  except Exception as e:
    print(e.__class__.__name__)
    print(e)
    exit()

  finally:
    sys.stdout.write("\n")
```

Can anyone help me? This is annoying because without the progress bar, everything would work perfectly fine.
I tried commenting this line, but then the error moves somewhere else, at line 300 (*requests.post*).

---

My infos :

**python --version** => Python 2.7.13

**Raspbian version** => PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure the combined file size is not larger than 4 GB? I think you're hitting this Python ["bug"](https://bugs.python.org/issue21444) as your Pi probably runs 32bit.
The issue is mentioned in `requests_toolbelt`'s [code](https://github.com/requests/toolbelt/blob/master/requests_toolbelt/multipart/encoder.py#L132) as well.
To fix this you need a more recent version of **requests_toolbelt** (I tested successfully with `0.6.0`) and a small change to **beam** itself:

```py
theProgressBar = ProgressBar(
    maxval = fileMPE.len,
    widgets = WIDGETS,
)
```

Comment: Thanks for that! But now the error is the same but later in the program. It happens in the "requests.post" part. And yes, I tried with files between 1Gb and 4Gb.

Comment: Can you post the full traceback for `requests.post` exception?

Comment: Where do I find it? It just says "OverflowError
long int too large to convert to int" I know it is in the requests.post because I used "print("test") a cross the program to find out where it crashes. Otherwise I'm in the blind.. :/

Comment: The traceback is the complete error message you get (it should include line numbers and files on which the error occurred).

Comment: Thanks, but where do I find it? On my console it only shows the Overflow error, and that's it.

Comment: Here is a pastebin of a traceback attempt : [https://pastebin.com/4WTcUink](https://pastebin.com/4WTcUink)

Comment: Here is another one with only n(ext) commands during debug. [https://pastebin.com/r9LZaVYz](https://pastebin.com/r9LZaVYz) -- FYI, I added `print("test 7")` between "urlParams" (l.294) and "requests.post" (l.300)

Comment: The full message wasn't shown because the Exception was caught and only  the class and message was printed; I debugged the code a little and found a solution (see updated answer).